# Why isn't my HTML Input displaying the "Cap" when I input "1 / 1" in the popup?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!-- visualization of number equating to sign -->
<input id="myInput" type="text"/>
<input id="signCall" type="text"/>
<!-- end -->



<script>

//Inputs prompts
var month = Number(window.prompt("Please input your birth month in numerical format"));
var day = Number(window.prompt("Please input your birth day of the month in numerical format"));

//logic to determine sign
var date = month * 100 + day;

//Declaring astrological signs
var cap;
var virgo;
var aries;
var libra;

//Declaring astroligical sign values
var cap = 101 <= date >= 119 || 1222 <= date >= 1231;
var aries = 321 <= date >= 331 || 401 <= date >= 419;


//connects to HTML to see number equating to sign
document.getElementById("myInput").value = date;

if (date == cap){
    signCaller = "Cap";
}

document.getElementById("signCall").value = signCaller;



</script>
```

I'm very confused. When the popup appears, I type in 1 for month and 1 for day. This should spit out the second input box (signCall) as "Cap". What exactly do I need to modify to make signCaller spit out "Cap" properly?

Comment: `101 <= 101` = true. `true >= 119` = false. `false || anything` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Your boolean equality tests have the second `<=` flipped, making it impossible for `date` to ever fulfill them

[jsfiddle with edits](https://jsfiddle.net/davidgamero/mxb7upg0/6/)

```
var cap = 101 <= date >= 119 || 1222 <= date >= 1231;
var aries = 321 <= date >= 331 || 401 <= date >= 419;
```

If you flip the `>=` then it becomes possible

```
var cap = 101 <= date <= 119 || 1222 <= date <= 1231;
var aries = 321 <= date <= 331 || 401 <= date <= 419;
```

Also since `cap` is a boolean, you can just do

```
if (cap){
    signCaller = "Cap";
}
```

Edit:

Since you have a series of inputs and outputs, a map is a better data structure for this problem.
A list of elements with each range, and what text it maps to, could be used to make a more repeatable pattern that would work with all the signs.

```
var dateRangeList = [
    [101,119,"Cap"],
    [1222,1231,"Cap"],
    [321,331,"Aries"],
    [401,419,"Aries"]
];

//connects to HTML to see number equating to sign
document.getElementById("myInput").value = date;

dateRangeList.forEach(
    (dateRange) => {
    let min = dateRange[0];
    let max = dateRange[1];
    let signText = dateRange[2];

    if(min <= date && date <= max){
        signCaller = signText
    }
  }
);
```

[jsfiddle for mapping approach](https://jsfiddle.net/davidgamero/d79cuyne/3/)

Comment: if (cap){
    signCaller = "Cap";
} this doesn't work if I make several of these with aries, etc

Comment: i've updated my answer to include mapping instead of using a variable per sign for a more sustainable pattern

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes:

1) This condition will return false:

> 101 <= date >= 119 || 1222 <= date >= 1231;

If we replace the value accordingly to your input, we get something like this:

> 101 <= 101 >= 119 || 1222 <= 101 >= 1231

The number 101 is indeed less than or equals to 101, but it is not greater than or equals 119, then this expression will return false. Also it's better to make multiple conditions for better readability, like this:

> (101 <= date && date >= 119) || (1222 <= date && date >= 1231)

2) You are trying to compare a number with a boolean:

```
if (date == cap){
    signCaller = "Cap";
}
```

If we replace the variables, we get something like this:

```
if (101 == false)
```

Didn't you mean just to test the "cap" variable? Like this:

```
if (cap)
```